# How to delete/remove/destroy/unload jQuery from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, destroy

I have jQuery on my web page, and I want to remove it programmatically.

Meaning completely unload it, destroy the object and related functions, destroy its internal memory allocations, and event bindings.

How can this be done?

Comment: jQuery is changing the DOM. I'm not totally sure but those changes will not be undone. It sounds that you need jQuery just as dependency for a third plugin. Maybe it's easier to rewrite that plugin.

Comment: Why should you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I don't know about internal memory allocations or event bindings, but `delete window.$; delete window.jQuery;` *might* work

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - I already tried it and it does not prevent jQuery events from firing.

Comment: @Malki: destroying/removing jQuery will not remove any event handlers it connected. They are just functions connected to DOM element events.  That is like saying *killing the builder will remove the house they built* :)

Comment: @Malki You may want to look into [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) - maybe `$("*").unbind().off()`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I don't think that's accurate. I think jQuery has its own internal mechanism for event binding/handling. On some basic level I'm sure it has to bind events to the DOM, but I think those are "general" jQuery handlers which then call the callbacks the user defined. So if there is a way to kill jQuery then it will no longer call the users callbacks

Comment: @Malki Is it something personal between you and jQuery?